# How to create custom HTML output for an existing Asciidoctor Asciidoc macro?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

For example, I want to add the [`loading="lazy"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321907/how-do-you-make-images-load-lazily-only-when-they-are-in-the-viewport/57389607#57389607) attribute to all my images e.g.:

```
image::myimage.jpg[]
```

but the default HTML `<img>` element output does not have that attribute.

Maybe this is was asked at: [Creating custom HTML with asciidoctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349585/creating-custom-html-with-asciidoctor) but the question is not clear enough for me to be sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented at: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#provide-custom-templates but it feels like a minimal example would be beneficial.

main.adoc

```
image::myimage.jpg[]
```

template_dir/block_image.html.erb

```
<%#encoding:UTF-8%><div<%= @id && %( id="#{@id}") %> class="<%= ['imageblock',@style,role].compact * ' ' %>"<%
if (attr? :align) || (attr? :float)
%> style="<%= [("text-align: #{attr :align};" if attr? :align),("float: #{attr :float};" if attr? :float)].compact * ' ' %>"<%
end %>>
<div class="content"><%
if attr? :link %>
<a class="image" href="<%= attr :link %>"><img src="<%= image_uri(attr :target) %>" loading="lazy" alt="<%= attr :alt %>"<%= (attr? :width) ? %( width="#{attr :width}") : nil %><%= (attr? :height) ? %( height="#{attr :height}") : nil %>></a><%
else %>
<img src="<%= image_uri(attr :target) %>" loading="lazy" alt="<%= attr :alt %>"<%= (attr? :width) ? %( width="#{attr :width}") : nil %><%= (attr? :height) ? %( height="#{attr :height}") : nil %>><%
end %>
</div><%
if title? %>
<div class="title"><%= captioned_title %></div><%
end %>
</div>
```

This is a copy the default template from https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-backends/blob/master/erb/html5/block_image.html.erb, but with the HTML modified by adding `loading="lazy"`.

Gemfile

```
gem 'asciidoctor', '2.0.10'
gem 'concurrent-ruby', '1.1.7'
gem 'tilt', '2.0.10'
```

We need to install those extra gems for it to work.

Compile:

```
asciidoctor --template-dir template_dir main.adoc
```

and that's it, the output HTML now contains `loading="lazy"`.

Tested in Asciidoctor 2.0.10.